# What is the correct way to write a file on Scrapinghub?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I use Python-Scrapy and Scrapinghub.

In my spider I should read and write a file

```
data_directory  = 'tmp'
csv_magasin = data_directory+"/"+current_script+"_"+current_date+"-shop_url.csv"

if not os.path.exists(data_directory):
    os.makedirs(data_directory)
try:
    os.remove('products.db')
except:
    pass
f = open('products.db', 'w')
f.write(t.content)
f.close
con = sqlite3.connect("products.db")
c = con.cursor()
```

When I run my spider on my server it works, but on Scrapinghub i can't read or write any file.

I read **[the doc](https://doc.scrapinghub.com/)**  but i didn't find how can i write a file in **Scrapinghub**.
My question is what is the correct way to write a file on Scrapinghub

Comment: Files on Scrapinghub are ephemeral and don't survive the job lifetime, what do you use the sqlite db for?

Comment: @PabloHoffman hey Pablo, i should delete my question because the way that i write the file is correct, 2 days ago, scrapinghub had a problem and i though that it's me, but it's was a technical  problem of scrpainghub